# How to make changes to a DocumentSnapshot/QueryDocumentSnapshot (FlutterFire)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make changes to a specific field in a DocumentSnapshot, but I cant figure out how to get the update method to work. I can't even find any documentation to help me figure it out.

```
whatever.data().update("Availability", (newValue) => whatever);
```

whatever is a documentsnapshot,'Availabilty' is the field I want to update,
and 'newValue' is the value I want to update the field in the fetched object itself and not in Firestore.

Answer (score 3):

The [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) has a `reference` property which is the [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) of this snapshot.

Then you can update the document like this:

```
whatever.reference.update({Availability: "NewValue"})
```

Edit: OP wanted to updated local variable only and not the data in Firestore which can be done by assigning the data to a variable and update it.

```
var myData = whatever.data()
myData['property'] = 'value'
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works, but I only want to change the value of the DocumentSnapshot object that I have in my list, not the document itself on the cloud. I only want the changes to take place when I press a confirmation button.  To give you a better idea of what im trying to do, im retrieving all my documents from firestore(as documentsnapshots) when the app starts and placing them into a list. This list is then used to populate a datatable. I only want to make changes to the documentsnapshots in the list and not the document itself.

Comment: @AsfandSalamAlavi can you share a screenshot of your document? Are you referring to an array in the document or something?

Comment: No. I'm referring to what my program does. If I use the reference property it makes direct changes to the database on the cloud, i dont want that. I only want it to change the field values of the snapshot itself.

Comment: @AsfandSalamAlavi you can just assign the data to a var like this `var myData = whatever.data()` and then change it like `myData['Availability'] = 'newValue'` and then `print(myData)` to check it. If my answer was helpful, you can upvote it and if it worked accept is by clicking the up arrow and tick icon respectively. [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: This works but for some reason, it changes back to the original value as soon as I make the change.

Comment: @AsfandSalamAlavi you should use the `myData` object only thereafter and not `whatever.data()` to use updated data.

Comment: Is there no way to update the documentsnapshot(whatever) directly, rather that storing its data in a separate variable and then updating it.

Comment: You would have to assign it somewhere else. There may be any way but what's wrong with assigning a new variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234757/discussion-between-asfand-salam-alavi-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('YOURCOLLECTION')
        .doc(DOCUMENTID)
        .update({'Availability': newValue}).then((value) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Success'),
          ),
        );
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error while updating document'),
        ),
      );
    });
```

`YOURCOLLECTION` is the name of your collection and `DOCUMENTID` is your document Id for which you want to update the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
whatever.doc().update({
        "Availability": newValue,
      });
```

Comment: I get this error "The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'."

Comment: I referenced to a particular post so it was doc(user.id) something like this
Reference it to a Document Reference